# React without npm

Tags: reactjs

How to import js file with code on Babel if i'm not using npm? I'm write my own server on Golang and serving html and js files.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TODO APP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    <script type='text/babel' src="./js/App.js"></script>
    <script type='text/babel' src="./js/Info.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <span onClick={() => {alert('clicked')}}>{Date.now().toString()}</span>
        <Info />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Info.js

```
export default class Info extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isOpen: true,
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    render() {
        const text = <label htmlFor="new-text">{this.state.isOpen ? 'Open' : "Closed"}</label>
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    {text}
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
    handleClick(e) {
        this.setState({
            isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
        })
    }
}
```

So i didn't know how to add Info to App. **import didn't work** cause i'm not using npm.

Comment: _"import didn't work cause i'm not using npm"_ - it's not about if you're using npm or not, import depends on EScript version. What about `require`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import and export won't work. You need to add the script tags in proper order so that the dependencies are resolved.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Order is important -->
    <script src="/info.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    <script src="/index.js" type="text/babel"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**info.js**

```
class Info extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        Hello World Info
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        Hello World
        <Info/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: ok, it's works. But if i have a lot of js files, i still should add it like this?

Comment: Yes, unless you are using module loader like webpack, you will have to manage the dependencies manually.

Comment: @Santosh I did same, But getting errors like:

1. babel.min.js:24 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/upforce/workspace/unNpmReact/info.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy:

2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined

3. babel.min.js:24 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/upforce/workspace/unNpmReact/app.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy